# How to make paste the content of the X selection as plain text

Tags: x11

I often copy contents of a Web site displayed on Firefox to LibreOffice Writer (which I'm forced to use by government administrators), and I really like to use the X selection by highlighting middle-clicking.  The default behavior is to copy the style present on the Web page into LibreOffice, which is not what I want.

How can I force the content of SELECTION to be always plain text?  I could do this by running `xclip` every 100 ms or so, but I'd rather have a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X selections are not just one thing: plain text, images, etc. They are often multiple at the same time in the form of what are called "targets":

```
% xclip -sel clip -o -t TARGETS                                                                                                            
TIMESTAMP               
TARGETS
SAVE_TARGETS
MULTIPLE
STRING
UTF8_STRING
TEXT
text/plain
text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

What targets are available will depend on what you have copied and what the application you've copied it from chose to offer.

Presumably in your `xclip` loop you are simply pasting and copying in again, which both likely uses a version that looks like plain text to you, and also makes xclip the owner of the selection instead of the original application.

What you could do instead of this loop is to run a script like this at paste time using whatever binds are provided by your window manager or desktop environment, using `text/plain` or an alternative similar target:

```
#!/bin/bash
out=$(xclip -sel PRIMARY -o -t text/plain; printf x)
xdotool type "${out%x}"
```

<sup>* The printf/strip makes sure trailing lines are kept, which otherwise would be stripped by the command substitution.</sup>

Comment: I didn't know window managers offered such callbacks.  What's the mechanism for Gnome?